# RemoeMediator Youtube Api v3 with Room nextPageToken

Tags: android, android-paging

I am having issues regarding pagination and saving results into remoteMediator

I need to save nextPageToken into database as

> `abstract fun pagingPopularItems(): PagingSource<String, PopularItemEntity>`

but I cannot because Room :
`error: For now, Room only supports PagingSource with Key of type Int.`

Is there a way to save nextPageToken into Int or a way around it?
Currently RemoteMediator only displays two API calls

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class PopularRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
private val popularDataSource: PopularDataSource,
private val popularDataStorage: PopularDataStorage,
private val sharedPreferencesManager: SharedPreferencesManager
) : RemoteMediator<Int, PopularItemDTO>() {

override suspend fun load(
    loadType: LoadType,
    state: PagingState<Int, PopularItemDTO>
): MediatorResult {
    return try {
        val nextPageToken = sharedPreferencesManager.getString(Setting.NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN) ?: EMPTY_STRING
        val loadKey: Int = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> 1
            LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(
                endOfPaginationReached = true
            )

            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val lastItem = state.lastItemOrNull()
                if (lastItem == null) {
                    1
                } else {
                    (lastItem.databaseId / state.config.pageSize) + 1
                }
            }
        }

        val pageToken = if (loadKey == 1) EMPTY_STRING else nextPageToken

        val popularResponse = popularDataSource.getPopularVideos(
            regionCode = "US",
            pageToken = pageToken
        )

        sharedPreferencesManager.setString(
            Setting.NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN,
            popularResponse.data!!.nextPageToken ?: EMPTY_STRING
        )
        sharedPreferencesManager.setString(
            Setting.PREV_PAGE_TOKEN,
            popularResponse.data!!.prevPageToken ?: EMPTY_STRING
        )

        if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
            popularDataStorage.clearPopulars()
        }

        popularDataStorage.upsertPopular(popularResponse.data)

        MediatorResult.Success(
            endOfPaginationReached = popularResponse.data!!.items!!.isEmpty()
        )
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        MediatorResult.Error(e)
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        MediatorResult.Error(e)
    }
}
}
```